# is there an index or list where i can find all the different "code words" for roblox lua coding?

Tags: lua, roblox

Basically, had an idea for a cool roblox game that uses little coding, and i cant code using roblox lua, but ive realised its easier for me to code if i have a big index, or list, that tells me each line (like "if" or "elif" that kind of stuff, keywords) that is usable in the code, so i can basically use it to hodge podge together a game with little to no outside help, but i cant find one, anybody know a place.

looked some stuff up, nothing for what i was looking for.

Comment: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3

Comment: thanks brian61354270

Comment: You'll also need the [Roblox API Ref](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine). handy, if you haven't already.

Comment: @Brian61354270, that link is great, but Roblox uses a fork of 5.1, not 5.2. The differences are probably minimal, but worth mentioning.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.